# django: How to render CharField as right to left?

Tags: django, python-3.x

In my app `froms.py` I defined my textfield as:

```
class ContactForm(forms.ModelForm):
    first_name = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(
        attrs={
            'class': 'form-control',
            'placeholder': 'نام'
        }
    ))
```

but as it can be seen in the screenshot, the text of placeholder and the actual text (that user would add) is being rendered left to right. How can I make it to render in right to left form?

[image]

Comment: What if you add `dir: 'rtl'` in the `attrs`?

Comment: That did the job man. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can specify the direction (`dir`) of *right-to-left* (`rtl`):

```
class ContactForm(forms.ModelForm):
    first_name = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(
        attrs={
            'class': 'form-control',
            'dir': 'rtl',
            'placeholder': 'نام'
        }
    ))
```